# Android - getActivity() returning null from dialogFragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-dialogfragment

I am reasonably new to fragments, so I apologise if this is quite basic.

My app contains a ViewPager to swipe between several different tabs with ListViews. On clicking one particular ListView item, I would like to open a DialogFragment displaying some options. My intention is to have the DialogFragment deal with the click event and feed the selected dialog item back to the fragment that called it. I am doing this by providing a callback to MainActivity (which contains the ViewPager) and feeding that information down to the correct ViewPager fragment.

What I have noticed is that my DialogFragment is returning null on getActivity(), which I believe is because my DialogFragment is not correctly attached to my MainActivity. How can I achieve this? I find it a little harder to navigate through this issue considering I am new to callbacks and most other examples dealing with fragments are for standard fragments, not those from ViewPager.

How can my dialog identify the correct activity? Should I be attaching the fragment to a FragmentManager? If so, should it be attached to the same FragmentManager as the ViewPager fragments?

This is my code, though I'm not sure how helpful it will be.

CalibrationFragment.java - Calling the DialogFragment. (Not sure if this is the correct way to do it.)

```
ModeDialogFragment modeDialog = ModeDialogFragment.newInstance(R.string.mode_calibration);
modeDialog.onCreateDialog(null);
```

ModeDialogFragment.java - My DialogFragment

```
public class ModeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

    public static ModeDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {
        ModeDialogFragment frag = new ModeDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);

        return frag;
    }

    public void onAttach(Activity activity){
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int title = getArguments().getInt("title");
        final Context mContext = getActivity();
        getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(newInstance(R.string.mode_calibration), "my_fragment").commit();
        // Trying to add my dialog to the MainActivity, not working.

        final CharSequence[] modeItems = {
                "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"
        };
        final int checkedItem = 2; // Make final for now, resolve this later

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.mode_calibration));
            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(modeItems, checkedItem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                // Handle the selection here

                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).updateModeData();
            }
        });
        return(builder.create());
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        // Initialise variables
        private Context mContext;
        // [Others...]

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Initialisation
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            actionBar = getActionBar();
            mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    }

   public Fragment findFragmentByPosition(int position) {
        int viewId = R.id.pager;
        //FragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter = getFragmentPagerAdapter();
        return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                makeFragmentName(viewId, position));
    }

    // Needed to identify a fragment from ViewPager
    private static String makeFragmentName(int viewId, int position)
    {
         return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + position;
    }

    public void updateModeData(){
        // Make call to the fragment to deal with the data
        CalibrationFragment calFragment = (CalibrationFragment) findFragmentByPosition(3);
        ((CalibrationFragment) calFragment).doUpdateModeData();
        }
}
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

**EDIT:** The problem was indeed that I was not adding the fragment to a FragmentManager and calling it correctly. This is the code I used. *My code still does not run through in its entirety*, but for the purpose of this question, my DialogFragment can now access MainActivity.

CalibrationFragment.java - Calling DialogFragment

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

ModeDialogFragment modeDialog = ModeDialogFragment.newInstance(R.string.mode_calibration);
String title = makeFragmentName(R.id.pager, 3); // makeFragmentName as specified in MainActivity.java
modeDialog.show(ft, title);
```

ModeDialogFragment.java is the same as before, but with the following line removed:

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(newInstance(R.string.mode_calibration), title).commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call `onCreateDialog` by yourself. Just call `show` method with `FragmentTransaction`:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ModeDialogFragment modeDialog = ModeDialogFragment.newInstance(R.string.mode_calibration);
modeDialog.show(ft, null);
```

Right usage of `DialogFragment` is described here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: Thanks - I knew something was off there, but wasn't sure what. I have found that if I use the support libraries for Fragment handling, .show() can't take a FragmentTransaction as a parameter, it wants a FragmentManager. If I use the standard libraries, my MainActivity complains. I will play around with these for a bit and reply once I make some progress.

Comment: @clb9355 You're welcome. If you use support library, then you must use it every where: instead of `Activity` use `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`